# Refactoring ASP.NET -- Two controls both inherit from Web.UI.UserControl and have same property

Tags: c#, asp.net, user-controls

I currently have this code, which I know is terrible, and I would like to refactor it as simply as possible.

```
if (control as HistoricalLineGraph != null)
{
    dock.Title = string.Format(format, dock.ChartName, (control as HistoricalLineGraph).Title);
}
else if (control as HistoricalPieGraph != null)
{
    dock.Title = string.Format(format, dock.ChartName, (control as HistoricalPieGraph).Title);
}
```

HistoricalLineGraph and HistoricalPieGraph both inherit from System.Web.UI.UserControl.

```
public partial class HistoricalLineGraph : System.Web.UI.UserControl
public partial class HistoricalPieGraph : System.Web.UI.UserControl
```

and they both have this getter:

```
public string Title
{
    get { return Chart1.Titles[0].Text; }
}
```

Since getting the title relies on Chart1 being instantiated it isn't (easily) possible to extract this getter to a common base class. I believe I'd need to use composite controls to do such a thing, but I am not entirely positive as I have not explored that solution in-depth.

Is it possible to do something akin to creating a middle-man class that inherits from System.Web.UI.UserControl and that has an abstract getter for Title which is then overridden by each of my above classes? If not, what are my other options?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can create an interface

```
public interface ITitledControl
{
       string Title {get;}
}
```

and use

```
public partial class HistoricalLineGraph : System.Web.UI.UserControl, ITitledControl
public partial class HistoricalPieGraph : System.Web.UI.UserControl, ITitledControl
```

and do this

```
if (control is ITitledControl)
{
    dock.Title = string.Format(format, dock.ChartName, (control as ITitledControl ).Title);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I would actually say that your best option is to create an interface which both controls implement. This means that you can have custom implementations if necessary, but simply cast the control to your interface and get the title.